# Combinatorial inequality in Erdös-Kac proof.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I am reading a proof of Erdös-Kac theorem, in Durrett, "Probability: Theory and Examples", fourth edition. In some point, it is stated that

$(\sum_{m=1}^nEZ_{n,m}^2)^k - \sum_{i_j} EZ_{n,i_1}^2 . EZ_{n,i_2}^2 ... EZ_{n,i_k}^2 \leq {k \choose 2} (2\epsilon_n)^2 (\sum_{m=1}^nEZ_{n,m}^2)^{k-1}$

Where $i_j$ extends over all $k$-tuples of positive distinct integers with $1 \leq i \leq n$, and it is knwon that $|Z_{m,s}| \leq \epsilon_n$.

The book states that you can see this is true because:

> " we note that for any $1 \leq a < b \leq k$ we can estimate the sum over all the $i_1, ..., i_k$ with $i_a = i_b$ by repacling $EZ_{n,i_a}^2$ by $(2\epsilon_n)$ to get the inequality above (the factor ${k \choose 2}$ giving the number of ways to pick $1 \leq a < b \leq k$).

I just don't understand the text of the argument; for a start I cannot see how it can be $i_a = i_b$ when $a < b$ since, by definition, the $i_j$  range over *different* integers.

At his point, the inequality $\sum_{i_j} EZ_{n,i_1}^2 . EZ_{n,i_2}^2 ... EZ_{n,i_k}^2 \leq (\sum_{m=1}^nEZ_{n,m}^2)^k$ is kown to hold.

I am sorry for asking such a general question, but as I said, I believe I might be misunderstanding even what's being stated in the proof (english is not my mother language). I appreciate very much every piece of hlep, and thak you very much in advance.